# How to call API multiple times in one method?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I have setup an API service in my angular project where I will store all of my API request code. The service contains methods like this:

```
  getMeeting(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.SERVER_URL}/meetings/${id}`).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched meeting id=${id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>(`getMeeting id=${id}`))
    );
  }
```

My component calls the method like this:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = +this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');

    this.apiService.getMeeting(id)
    .subscribe((res: any) => {
      this.meeting = res;
      console.log(this.meeting);
    }, err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
```

The meeting result contains some id's which relate to data from my other API resources, e.g. (`meeting.eventId`). What is the recommended approach to making a second API call using the `meeting.eventId` from the first response?

I don't want there to be any visible delay in the UI where content sequentially appears as it's loaded. Rather, I want to display data in the UI once all calls are done.

Comment: You can try putting the "this.meeting = res;" assignment after the second API call so the all content appears in the same time?

Answer (score 0):

you could handle the two api requests and return the two results like this:

```
 getMeeting(id: number): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.SERVER_URL}/meetings/${id}`).pipe(
      tap(_ => console.log(`fetched meeting id=${id}`)),
      switchMap(responseFromFirstRequest => {
        //. handle the next api request here and then return the result
        return this.nextApiCall(responseFromFirstRequest).pipe(
          map(secondResponse => {
            return {
              firstResult: responseFromFirstRequest,
              secondResult: secondResponse
            };
          })
        );
      }),
      catchError(this.handleError<any>(`getMeeting id=${id}`))
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `forkJoin` operation from rxjs library. Having your method:

```
getMeeting(id: number): Observable<any> {
  return this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.SERVER_URL}/meetings/${id}`).pipe(
    tap(_ => console.log(`fetched meeting id=${id}`)),
    catchError(this.handleError<any>(`getMeeting id=${id}`))
  );
}
```

You would call the API multiple times in parallel like:

```
forkJoin([
  this.apiService.getMeeting(id1),
  this.apiService.getMeeting(id2)
]).subscribe(([res1, res2])=> console.log({res1, res2}));
```

Or in series:

```
this.httpClient.get<any>(`${this.SERVER_URL}/meetings/${id}`).pipe(
    tap(res => console.log('First result', res)),
    concatMap((res) => this.httpClient.get < any > (`${this.SERVER_URL}/meetings/${id2}`)),
    tap(res => console.log('Second result', res))
).subscribe(res => console.log('Latest result', res));
```

Answer (score -1):

```
this.apiService.getMeeting(id).pipe(
  concatMap(meeting => otherCall(meeting).pipe(
    map(other => [meeting, other]),
  )),
)
.subscribe(([meeting, other]) => {
  ...
});
```

Comment: This works, but I don't understand the downvote?

Comment: Please include an explanation of what the code does and why it solves the problem.

Comment: @dom_ahdigital I don't understand it either. But this is the easiest way to do it. I think it should be pretty straight forward.